Ltac for deterministic rewriting/sorting of operands
I would like to create Coq tactics for solving a wide range of equality subgoals that may be solved by using a mix of rewrite rules such as associativity and commutativity of operators.
Although this is not my end goal, a simple example would be to solve equality of sums, e.g. show that a + b + c + d = a + (d + c) + b for instance.
I know that I can do this using a rule like:
Require Import FMapList OrderedTypeEx List Rdefinitions Raxioms RIneq.
Open Scope R.

Ltac sort_sums_step :=
  let rec solve_sub_equality sub_equality :=
    lazymatch sub_equality with
    | ?a + ?c = ?b + ?c => solve_sub_equality (a = b)
    | ?a + ?c = ?b + ?d => rewrite (Rplus_comm (b) (d)); repeat rewrite <- (Rplus_assoc _ _ _)
    | _ => fail
    end
  in
  lazymatch goal with
  | |- ?a => solve_sub_equality a
  end.

Ltac solve_sum_equality :=
  repeat rewrite <- (Rplus_assoc _ _ _); repeat sort_sums_step; reflexivity.

Theorem TestEasyTheorem (a b c d:R) : a + b + c + d = a + (d + c) + b.
Proof.
  solve_sum_equality.
Qed.

The 'problem' with these tactics is that they're just trying to swap terms blindly, and while this works well here for a simple sum, if we mix in other operators like multiplication, division, etc., randomly trying out all the swaps would blow up in complexity and the tactic would take forever to compute.
Thus, I'm trying to code a 'smart' tactic that decides on a specific ordering of operands (ideally just built based on the goal itself, rather than explicitly provided to the tactic), and then sorts both sides of the equation based on that ordering to a unique canonical form (so that a mere reflexity may then solve the equality goal).
Is this possible in Coq, and how should I got about it?


Note on what I tried out:
I managed to make a tactic that, given an ordering of operands, builds the list of indices of the operands in the sum (which could potentially later be used to re-order them):

Ltac reverse_indices_of_left_sum_in_list l :=
  let rec id_index id lst :=
    lazymatch lst with
    | id::?q => O
    | ?a::?q => let idx1 := (id_index id q) in (constr:(S idx1))
    | _ => fail "1"
    end
  in
  let rec build_list sum_expr :=
    lazymatch sum_expr with
    | ?a + ?b => let q := (build_list a) in let idxb := (id_index b l) in (constr:(cons idxb q))
    | ?a => let idx := (id_index a l) in (constr:(cons idx nil))
    end
  in
  lazymatch goal with
  | |- ?a = ?b => let test := build_list a in pose (foo := test)
  | |- _ => fail "2"
  end.


Theorem TestEasyTheorem2 (a b c d:R) : (a + d + c + b)%R = (a + b + c + d)%R.
Proof.
  reverse_indices_of_left_sum_in_list (a::b::c::d::nil).
  (* Defines: foo := 1%nat :: 2%nat :: 3%nat :: 0%nat :: nil : list nat *)
Admitted.

However, when I try to use the indices to sort the sums, none of my attempts succeeded. For instance:
Ltac sort_sums_step l :=
  let rec id_index id lst :=
    lazymatch lst with
    | id::?q => O
    | ?a::?q => let idx1 := (id_index id q) in (constr:(S idx1))
    | _ => fail "Identifier not found: " id
    end
  in
  let rec sort_sums sum_expr :=
    lazymatch sum_expr with
    | ?a + ?b + ?c => sort_sums (a + b) || (
      let idx_cmp := (compare (id_index b l) (id_index c l)) in
      match (eval compute in idx_cmp) with
      | Lt => fail "All good"
      | Eq => fail "All good"
      | Gt => rewrite (Rplus_assoc a b c); rewrite (Rplus_comm b c); rewrite <- (Rplus_assoc a c b)
      end)
    | ?b + ?c => let idx_cmp := compare (id_index b l) (id_index c l) in
      match (eval compute in idx_cmp) with
      | Lt => fail "All good"
      | Eq => fail "All good"
      | Gt => rewrite (Rplus_comm b c)
      end
    | ?a => fail "All good"
    end
  in
  lazymatch goal with
  | |- ?a = ?b => sort_sums a || sort_sums b
  | |- _ => fail "2"
  end.

Theorem TestEasyTheorem2 (a b c d:R) : (a + d + c + b)%R = (a + b + c + d)%R.
Proof.
  sort_sums_step (a::b::c::d::nil).

fails with:
Variable id_index should be bound to a term but is bound to a tacvalue.

I also get a similar error when I try to build the list from the goal itself:
Ltac build_list :=
  let rec add_to_list id lst :=
    lazymatch lst with
    | id::?q => constr:(cons id q)
    | ?a::?q => constr:(cons a (add_to_list id q))
    | @nil => constr:(cons id nil)
    end
  in
  let rec build_id_list sum_expr lst :=
    lazymatch sum_expr with
    | ?a + ?b =>
      let lst_with_a := eval compute in (build_id_list a lst) in
      let lst_with_b := eval compute in (build_id_list b lst_with_a) in
      lst_with_b
    | ?c =>
      eval compute in (add_to_list c lst)
    end
  in
  lazymatch goal with
  | |- ?a = ?b => let bar := build_id_list a nil in let baz := (eval compute in bar) in pose (foo := baz)
  | |- _ => fail "2"
  end.

Theorem TestEasyTheorem3 (a b c:R) : a + b + c = a + c + b.
Proof.
  build_list.

gives:
Variable build_id_list should be bound to a term but is bound to a tacvalue.


I can probably take a closer look at this if you want, but here, the manual page for Ltac (https://coq.inria.fr/doc/v8.11/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html) is your friend for debugging your problems with constr. The section on "Deciding Type Isomorphisms" also gives a similar example to what you're attempting here. If you just want an automagic way to solve these problems, ring (Require Import ZArith) and lia (Require Import Lia) are your ticket. Prefer separated Ltac definitions to mutually inductive let rec statements, and take advantage of continuation-passing style.

Also, I think you may be confusing the tactic compare with the term Nat.compare. If you make that switch and let-bind the results of the id_indexes before inserting them, you'll get a tactic that doesn't error.

Furthermore, you need to get rid of about all of the eval compute in statements in your second example, as none of them are syntactically valid. Also, replace @nil with nil and your last nil with nil : list R for typing reasons.

Perhaps you are doing this as an excercise and is not interested in a tool. But if not,  have you checked the coq library for rewriting  equations modulo associativity and commutativity, https://github.com/coq-community/aac-tactics ?
"The tactics can be applied for custom operators by registering the operators and their properties as type class instances. Instances for many commonly used operators, such as for binary integer arithmetic and booleans, are provided with the plugin."

Thank you both for the pointers!
I was looking into doing more than just these kinds of basic arithmetic rewrites, but these pre-made libraries do look useful.
As for fixing the definitions I was trying out, I tried to follow your suggestions @Feryll, but without much success. Notably, the part that I updated to:
let idx_b := id_index b l in let idx_c := id_index c l in let idx_cmp := Nat.compare idx_b idx_c in
now gives me The reference Nat.compare was not found in the current environment..

I guess it still gets interpreted as a tactic somehow? I found that using pose (idx_cmp := Nat.compare [...]) solves that particular issue (although I don't really want to pose a new variable). Although it seems like the comparison doesn't get evaluated since the follow-up match doesn't match on either 3 of Lt/Gt/Eq (this is why I tried using eval compute in).

Managed to make the sort_sums_step work!
I was also missing the constr:(...) prefix for when I call Nat.compare. Will try to apply the same guidelines to the more complex version when I don't pass the list of operands, and update back this post.

Thanks to Feryll's pointers, I managed to fix the two broken tactics in my question.
The main takeaway I was missing is that it's not possible to mix tactics and terms, and one needs to use things like constr:(...) to use (construct) a term in a tactic. Similarly, eval compute in ... is only useful on constructed terms, not tactic calls (which are directly evaluated).
Fixed code: (doesn't look great, and would probably benefit from the suggestions from the question comments, but at least it works)
Require Import Init.Datatypes FMapList Init.Nat OrderedTypeEx List Rdefinitions Raxioms RIneq.
Open Scope R.

Ltac sort_sums_step l :=
  let rec id_index id lst :=
    lazymatch lst with
    | id::?q => O
    | ?a::?q => let idx1 := id_index id q in (constr:(S idx1))
    | _ => fail "Identifier not found: " id
    end
  in
  let rec sort_sums sum_expr :=
    lazymatch sum_expr with
    | ?a + ?b + ?c => sort_sums (a + b) || (
      let idx_b := id_index b l in
      let idx_c := id_index c l in
      let idx_cmp := constr:(compare idx_b idx_c) in
      match (eval compute in idx_cmp) with
      | Lt => fail "All good"
      | Eq => fail "All good"
      | Gt => rewrite (Rplus_assoc a b c); rewrite (Rplus_comm b c); rewrite <- (Rplus_assoc a c b)
      end)
    | ?b + ?c =>
      let idx_b := id_index b l in
      let idx_c := id_index c l in
      let idx_cmp := constr:(compare idx_b idx_c) in
      (match (eval compute in idx_cmp) with
      | Lt => fail "All good"
      | Eq => fail "All good"
      | Gt => rewrite (Rplus_comm b c)
      end)
    | ?a => fail "All good"
    end
  in
  lazymatch goal with
  | |- ?a = ?b => sort_sums a || sort_sums b
  | |- _ => fail "2"
  end.

Ltac build_list :=
  let rec add_to_list id lst :=
    lazymatch lst with
    | id::?q => constr:(cons id q)
    | ?a::?q => let id_q := add_to_list id q in constr:(cons a id_q)
    | nil => constr:(cons id nil)
    end
  in
  let rec build_id_list sum_expr lst :=
    lazymatch sum_expr with
    | ?a + ?b =>
      let lst_with_a := (build_id_list a lst) in
      let lst_with_b := (build_id_list b lst_with_a) in
      lst_with_b
    | ?c =>
      (add_to_list c lst)
    end
  in
  lazymatch goal with
  | |- ?a = ?b => build_id_list a (nil: list R)
  | |- _ => fail "2"
  end.


Ltac solve_sum_equality :=
  repeat rewrite <- (Rplus_assoc _ _ _);
  let operands_list := build_list in
  repeat sort_sums_step operands_list;
  reflexivity.

Theorem TestEasyTheorem (a b c d:R) : a + b + c + d = a + (d + c) + b.
Proof.
  solve_sum_equality.
Qed.

